# Ubuntu 14.04 missing launcher (icons, time, wifi icon...)

Tags: 14.04, launcher

Ubuntu missing launcher (icons on left side, time, wifi icon, close/minimize/maximize buttons ...)

Here is a screenshot:[image]

There is no problem when I log in as a guest user.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like that compiz (the window-manager) has stopped working.
Open the Console (Ctrl + Alt + T) and enter simply enter "compiz".

If that doesnt work then your compiz is broken and needs to be repaired